oriented angle between the two vectors

Given two unit vectors $ \mathbf{u} $ and $ \mathbf{v} $. Prove
that $ (u,\dfrac{u+v}{|u+v|})=(\dfrac{u+v}{|u+v|},v) $ (where $(\mathbf{u},
 \mathbf{v})$ denotes the oriented angle between the two vectors).

I have $(u,\dfrac{u+v}{|u+v|})+(\dfrac{u+v}{|u+v|},v)=(u,v)$
$(a,b)=(c,d)$ iff there is a rotation s.t if $R^{\alpha}(a)=b$, then $R^{\alpha}(c)=d.$
Let $u,v$ be 2 unit vectors. Then there exists a unique rotation (counter-clockwise) s.t $R^{\alpha}(u)=v$. We call $\alpha$ the oriented angle between $u$ and $v$.
I don't have any idea to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

It's obvious if you draw a picture of the rhombus.

we can't prove something by drawing though

Well then, you will have to give us your definition of 'oriented angle'.

I added the definition

One problem with your scheme is that when $\textbf{u}$ and $\textbf{v}$ are unit vectors, there is no guarantee that $\frac{\textbf{u}+\textbf{v}}{2}$ is also a unit vector; take, for example, $\textbf{u} = \langle 1,0 \rangle$ and $\textbf{v}=\langle 0,1 \rangle$.

Another problem is that the logical structure of your "Also..." sentence doesn't hold together.

@LeeMosher I edited

The vectors are in $\mathbb R^2$?

@mr_e_man yes...

Use complex numbers. The angle $\alpha$ from $u$ to $v$ is given by
$$e^{i\alpha}u=v,$$
or equivalently, since $\overline uu=|u|^2=1$,
$$e^{i\alpha}=\overline uv.$$
Let $w=(u+v)/|u+v|$. We want to show that $\overline uw=\overline wv$. That is:
$$\overline u\frac{(u+v)}{|u+v|}\;\overset?=\;\frac{(\overline u+\overline v)}{|u+v|}v$$
$$\overline u(u+v)\;\overset?=\;(\overline u+\overline v)v$$
$$|u|^2+\overline uv\;\overset?=\;\overline uv+|v|^2$$
This is clearly true since $|u|=|v|=1$.

I know you mentioned you can't prove something by drawing, but the idea follows pretty quickly from the following idea: for isosceles triangles, the median to the third side is the same as the angle bisector. Draw the isosceles triangle formed by $0$, $u$ and $v$. $u + v$ is in the direction of the median, so since the triangle is isosceles, $u + v$ is also in the direction of the angle bisector, and now putting this in your notation, the result holds true.
Otherwise, you will have to use some ideas about $R^a$. The idea is that
$$(I+R^{2\alpha})(u) =  \lambda R^\alpha (u)$$
for some $\lambda$. If you know that $R^\alpha$ takes the form $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{pmatrix}$, then we can see:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\cos^2 \alpha & 2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha \\ -2\sin \alpha \cos \alpha & 2\cos^2 \alpha \end{pmatrix} = \lambda\begin{pmatrix} \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\ -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$
and you should be able to see what value of $\lambda$ makes this true. You can fill in the details! Notice that the fundamental thing I did for this second proof is just let $v = R^{2\alpha}(u)$. We can do this because we can take whatever angle $\beta$ there is counterclockwise between $v$ and $u$ and just split it in half (there is a result from linear algebra you can use if you would like to be more formal).
Notice that with these two proofs, it is very easy to generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I wonder which proof you like better?
